# How to remove the first row in every sheet in r?

Tags: r, xlsx

I have an excel document with multiple sheets. I was curious if there was a way to remove the first row of every sheet as there is a header file on the sheet that isn't necessary but this automatically appears on each sheet. I would rather not open the file and remove the first row as this can cause possible data errors.

Comment: Many functions that read-in data will have a "skip" argument (under some name). E.g., for `readxl::read_excel()` you can use `skip = 1` to skip one line.  If you check out the documentation for the function you are using it should help clarify things.

Comment: I didn't realize that. Thanks! I believe you answered my question. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Many functions that read-in data will have a "skip" argument (under some name). E.g., for `readxl::read_excel()` you can use `skip = 1` to skip one line. If you check out the documentation for the function you are using it should help clarify things."
- Andrew